# Generate String for file/directory name

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsfilemanager

I create a directory in the documents directory with the string @"My Folder" by pressing a button.
But if this directory already exist I want it to be named @"My Folder 1" and if this exists then @"My Folder 2" and so on..
How can I achieve this?

I test whether the directory already exists with this

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; 
    else {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for what you need.

```
int i = 0;
while ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Folder %i", i])
    i++;
}

NSString *folder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Folder %i", i];
[[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:folder withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
```